# How to stop my server from bruteforcing another

Tags: linux, malware, shared-hosting, brute-force-attacks, sysadmin

There are so many resources on how to stop bruteforce attacks on your server, but I can't find any good on bruteforce attacks FROM a **shared hosting** server.

I am getting a lot of reports from many different providers that my servers is attacking theirs. Even after scanning with ClamScan and removing a whole lot of malware.

Is there an easy way to see which website(or script) on my server is calling, lets say, "/wp-login.php" on another server?

Answer (score -1):

your best bet is to packet capture and analyse it with Wireshark.
you can put a IPS like snort or Suricata in af-paket mode betting the server and internet.